# R: How to Label Specific Contours using direct.label

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I'm relatively new to `ggplot2`, and I'm having trouble adding appropriate labels to my contours.

Using the classic volcano example, I can add labels to the default contour plot:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(reshape)
volcano<-melt(volcano)
v<-ggplot(volcano, aes(x,y,z=z))
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..))
direct.label(e)
```

In the above example, the labels are added appropriately, but things become more complicated if I try to specify my own break points for the contours:

```
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(breaks=c(160, 170, 180), colour=..level..))
direct.label(e)
```

Now, the contours are specified by the breaks I have provided, but labels still appear for all of the default contours. How do I only plot only labels for the graphed contours?

A related issue, how would I plot labels for contour levels not included in the default? Say a break of 165:

```
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(breaks=c(165), colour=..level..))
direct.label(e)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Its worth noting that direct.label() is in the directlabels package.

Comment: Should I re-post this question, or are people still looking at it?

Comment: I'd suggest you pose the question a slightly different way, and re-post it. Directlabel isn't a very widely-used package as far as I know. I bet there is an all-ggplot way to do what you want to do; I would drop the reference to direct.label() and see what other solutions people come up with.

Comment: Would love to know if anyone has figured this out.  Having the exact same issue

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't stand to see an old question unanswered with such an easy fix.

The simple problem was the mapping inside `stat_contour()`. Your call should be:

```
v<-ggplot(volcano, aes(x=X1,y=X2,z=value))  # specify the mapping properly
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..), breaks=c(160, 170, 180))
direct.label(e)
```

With the breaks not included in the aes mapping, and the `colour=..level..` included.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear to work with `ggplot2` version `>2.0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

with ggplot > 2.0.0 you'll need to add method="bottom.pieces" (or top.pieces) to the direct.label call

```
library(directlabels)
direct.label(e, method="bottom.pieces")
```